# Deploying C++ on NAO: "error while loading shared libraries libboost_thread.so.1.64.0: Cannot open shared object file"

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, nao-robot

I am working with the Nao-V6 robot and I am trying to cross-compile a program so that it can be executed standalone on the robot. The steps I followed were:

- I configured and built a package for a qiBuild project called **example.**
- I used 
  `scp example.zip nao@nao.local:.` to send it to the robot
- I tried to execute it on the Nao `./bin/example`, it throws this error: `./example: error while loading shared libraries libboost_thread.so.1.64.0: cannot open shared object file`.

Comment: Have you deployed the library? Is it in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH or registered in the system?

Comment: @SimonKraemer the robot OS does not have this file in the /usr/lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

QiBuild packages are made to integrate toolchains. By making a package, QiBuild avoids bringing in the dependencies, to avoid duplicate binaries in the toolchain.

Instead of making a package, use `qibuild deploy` to send it on the robot:

```
$ qibuild deploy <my_project> --url nao@nao.local:/home/nao/<my_project>
```

It uses `rsync` to send the files, so the dependencies will be transferred only the first time, making the next deployments faster.